# To retrieve data from database using union query

Tags: mysql

I want to retrieve data to get  `product_id` which equal other table `product_id` using union query. I want to join two table's `product_id` after I have joined two table with union query. I can't try it. Please help me.

```
$query_filter=mysql_query("SELECT  (select ttdbrand.name) as brand,
                                       (select cproduct_brand.product_id) as product_brand
                               FROM `taxonomy_term_data` as ttdbrand
                               INNER JOIN
                                    `node` as n
                               INNER JOIN       
                                    `field_data_field_brand` as fbrand
                               INNER JOIN
                                    `commerce_product` as cproduct_brand
                               INNER JOIN
                                    `field_data_field_product` as fproduct_brand

                               ON n.nid=fbrand.entity_id
                               AND ttdbrand.tid=fbrand.field_brand_tid  
                               AND fproduct_brand.entity_id=n.nid                                   
                               and  cproduct_city.product_id=cproduct_brand.product_id
                               HAVING brand in ('$data_brand')

                               UNION ALL

                               SELECT (select ttdcity.name ) as city,
                                      (select cproduct_city.product_id ) as product
                               FROM `taxonomy_term_data` as ttdcity
                               INNER JOIN
                                  `node` as n
                               INNER JOIN       
                                `field_data_field_city` as fcity
                               INNER JOIN
                                    `commerce_product` as cproduct_city
                               INNER JOIN
                                    `field_data_field_product` as fproduct_city                                     
                               ON n.nid=fcity.entity_id
                               AND ttdcity.tid=fcity.field_city_tid 
                               AND fproduct_city.entity_id=n.nid
                               AND cproduct_city.product_id=fproduct_city.field_product_product_id                                                             
                               HAVING city IN ('$data_city')                               
                               order by product_brand DESC

                               ") or die(mysql_error());


    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_filter)) {            
        $row_array[]=$row;                 
    }
```

Comment: Do both of the select queries work without the union?

Comment: `INNER JOIN  node as n` what is it? I think it ts wrong syntax of `Join`. And what error did you get?

Comment: JOIN x ON x... JOIN y ON y... JOIN z ON z... etc

Comment: Those two statements don't seem union compatible (at least not semantically). One is a brand and the other is a city. Maybe the data types don't match either. Are you sure union is the thing you really want to use?